# Error While Sending mail from Unix Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to send email from unix using below python code. I want to attach multiple files. But getting error - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /

```
'''
import sys
import smtplib
import os.path as op
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders


def send_mail(send_from, send_to, send_cc, subject, message, files=[],server="serveripaddress"):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = send_to
    msg['Cc'] = send_cc
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

    for path in files:
        print(path)
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            part.set_payload(file.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(op.basename(path)))
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to.split(', '), msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #assert len(sys.argv) >= 6

    #files=None

    #if len(sys.argv) == 7:
        #files = sys.argv[6]


    send_mail("receipient1@gmail.com", "receipient2@gmail.com", "receipient3@gmail.com", "hi", "This 
    is subject",['/home/test/folder1/file1.csv','/home/test/folder1/file2.csv'])
  

'''
```

On  with open(path, 'rb') as file: line I am getting IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/'
Not able to understand what is the issue since the path I have mentioned is present.

Comment: Did you checked how path looks?? Print it pls

Comment: Paste your send_mail() call with the args correctly.

Comment: @Wonka,print shows /

Comment: @lllrnr101, I have corrected code there was a syntax error on send_mail line it [ was not closed. After that it started workingl. But when externally I am sending arguments then it is failing with the error I have mentioned earlier.                                                    
  sendmail.py "receipient1@gmail.com", "receipient2@gmail.com", "receipient3@gmail.com", "hi", "This 
    is subject", ['/home/test/folder1/file1.csv','/home/test/folder1/file2.csv']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sys.argv you ae getting values in string. You are not converting that string arg to list in case of files.

So your files argument is treated as `"['/home/test/folder1/file1.csv','/home/test/folder1/file2.csv']"` which gives the error file not found because `for path in files` reads the arg one character at a time and not as you intend.

EDIT:
Converting it with `files=list(argv[6])` will NOT work.

Please use below approach:

```
import sys
print (sys.argv)
files = sys.argv[1]
print(f'files: {files}, type: {type(files)}')
files = [x.strip() for x in files.split(',')]
print(f'files: {files}, type: {type(files)}')
for filename in files:
    print(filename)
```

which on running `python sendmail.py  'file1,file2'` gives me below output:

```
['sendmail.py', 'file1,file2']
files: file1,file2, type: <class 'str'>
files: ['file1', 'file2'], type: <class 'list'>
file1
file2
```

So you have to pass the files to program in quotes and then within your program convert that to list and then pass to sendmail function.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. But after making that changes still it is not reading the path correctly. When I printerd print(path) and print(files) getting [

Comment: Can you print(files) before calling the send_mail() and show that output here in the question.

Comment: Very sorry to have confused you but my answer was wrong in converting the string to list. Please see the edit. That will work.

Comment: Perfect!! thanks. It's working now. Had to make few changes when there is no attachment.

Comment: Good to know! Glad to be of help.